# When should MapActivity.isRouteDisplayed() return true?

Tags: android

I have a question as to when [MapActivity.isRouteDisplayed()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html#isRouteDisplayed%28%29) needs to return a value of true. The javadoc gives the example of displaying driving directions as a reason to return true. Does anyone know if a value of true needs to be returned if the map is simply plotting a route that a device has traveled? For example, if the device recorded the GPS points it received in an internal database and simply plotted those points on a map. Does a value of true need to be returned in this case to be in compliance with the TOS?

Answer (score 0):

In the use case your provided there in no need to return true as you are not using it for vehicle tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does that mean that "route" indicates the path to be taken rather than the path already traveled?

Also, can you point me to any additional information other than the javadoc?